# How to enable multicast routing in TMG 2010?

Tags: routing, multicast, microsoft-ftmg-2010, microsoft-ftmg, igmp

I have a TMG 2010 firewall between some office networks, which handles routing and firewalling; I need to let some application-specific multicast traffic flow between these networks; this is UDP traffic on a custom port (10234), with destination multicast addresses in the form 224.X.Y.Z.

I already followed the steps [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/isablog/archive/2009/02/04/how-to-enable-multicast-routing-with-isa-server.aspx), but it doesn't work: TMG keeps complaining about the destination address being invalid.

---

**Denied Connection**
**Status:** An ingoing packet was dropped because its destination address does not exist on the system, and no appropriate forwarding interface exists.
**Rule:** None - see Result Code
**Source:** *SOURCE NETWORK AND ADDRESS*
**Destination:** External (224.0.1.1:10234)
**Protocol:** *CUSTOM UDP PROTOCOL*

---

1) Can TMG actually route this type of traffic?
2) How?

Comment: Should this be moved to networkengineering.stackexchange.com?

Comment: If someone there is able to answer, it's ok for me...